# Unable to accept Multiline Inputs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, runtime-error

I'am still learning but I'am unable to figure out why I'm I not able to input one input code below the other. :(

```
n = input("I/P n:")
r = input("I/P r:")
print(n, r)
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" F:/Softwares/PyCharm/Test.py
I/P n:8

8
I/P r:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It takes the input of n but not r it just skips what I just do is just press enter once after entering number.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.6.2.

Comment: just change r = input("I/P r:") to r = input()

Comment: Nope, that didn't make any difference!

Comment: Anyhow if I use:

`n,r = input("I/P n:").split(' ')
print("N=", n, "R=", r)`

Then it works, I even want that type of code to also work!